# Python iteration of list of objects "not iterable"

Tags: python, list, object, iteration

New to Python, but I have been researching this for a couple hours. Forgive me if I missed something obvious.

I have a class called LineItem, which has an attribute _lineItems, a list of LineItems that belong to the given LineItem. A sub-list, basically.

I want to print out a LineItem and all of its sub-items (and the sub-items own sub-items), but I'm having trouble with the iteration.

```
from decimal import * 
class LineItem(object):
    """
    Instance attributes:
      amount: Decimal
      _lineItems: list of child internal lineitems (possibly an empty list)
      isInternal: bool
    """

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.amount = Decimal(0)
        self._lineItems = []
        self.isInternal = False
        for k, v in kw.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

An example LineItem that's giving me the trouble is defined below as ext2, with three children.

```
# External line item with one level of children
int1 = LineItem(amount=Decimal('1886.75'), description='State Dues',
         isInternal=True)
int2 = LineItem(amount=Decimal('232.50'), description='National Dues',
         isInternal=True)
int3 = LineItem(amount=Decimal('50'), description='Processing Fee',
         isInternal=True)
ext2 = LineItem(amount=Decimal('2169.25'), description='Dues',
         _lineItems=[int1, int2, int3])
```

I have this recursive function for iterating all the sub-items (and printing them numbered, like 1, 2, 2.1 as the first subitem of the second item, etc)

```
def print_line_item(LineItems):
    count = 1
    for a in LineItems:
        print count, ' ', a.description, ' (', a.amount, ')'
        if a._lineItems != []:
            for b in a._lineItems:
                print count, '.', print_line_item(b),
        count+=1
```

but when I try to use it

```
def main():
    print_line_item([ext1, ext2, ext3]) #ext1 has no children, prints fine
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I get

```
line 56, in print_line_item
    print count, '.', print_line_item(b),
line 51, in print_line_item
    for a in LineItems:
TypeError: 'LineItem' object is not iterable
```

Okay, so somehow I'm screwing up lists.

if I add a couple print statements:

```
def print_line_item(LineItems):
    count = 1
    for a in LineItems:
        print count, ' ', a.description, ' (', a.amount, ')'
        if a._lineItems != []:
            print a._lineItems
            for b in a._lineItems:
                print b
                print count, '.', print_line_item(b),
        count+=1
```

I get proof that a._lineItems is indeed a list, printed as follows:

```
[<__main__.LineItem object at 0x0227C430>, <__main__.LineItem object at 0x0227C5F0>, <__main__.LineItem object at 0x0227C670>]
```

and that the b I'm trying to pass to the recursing call is a memory address of a single LineItem

```
<__main__.LineItem object at 0x0227C430>
```

Sooo how am I actually supposed to do what I'm trying to do? I tried a couple things with .iter or `___iter___` but no luck.

Also, the if a._lineItems != [] doesn't seem to be working either (nor variations on that). I get printed lines of "None"

Comment: Don't use `!= []`, use either `if a._lineItems` or `if len(a._lintItems)`.  Also, not to nit-pick, but this is not recursion.

Comment: How about you trim your Question down to a simple minimum reproducible example?

Comment: @sberry How is it not recursion?  print_line_item goes through and calls itself with the sublists

Comment: An SSCCE would be a good idea.  Also, you might try pylint - it's like an expert system about how to write good Python code.

Comment: (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example is what SSCCE stands for)

Comment: @Foon, indeed it does... I did not catch that.

Comment: @sberry I actually have tried both of those and still got "None" printouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def print_line_item(LineItems):
    count = 1
    for a in LineItems:
        print count, ' ', a.description, ' (', a.amount, ')'
        if a._lineItems != []:
            for b in a._lineItems:
                print count, '.', print_line_item(b),
        count+=1
```

It might be correct version, not tested.

```
def print_line_item(LineItems, precedingNumber='1'):
    count = 1
    for a in LineItems:
        print precedingNumber, '.', count, ' ', a.description, ' (', a.amount, ')'
        print_line_item(a._lineItems, precedingNumber + '.' + count),
        count+=1
```

Comment: Thanks Melug. This wasn't quite it but you got me much closer to a solution than anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense you're getting a not-iterable message--you're essentially recursing into print_line_item for each item in a list--and sooner or later, you'll hit something in a list that isn't iterable itself--and you just go on and call print_line_item() on it, which will try to iterate over it.

If you want to ask "is this item a list?" you could use `isinstance(some-object, list)`. Or, if you want to allow for other iterable-but-not-list-things, you can use `if isinstance(some-object, collections.Iterable)` (you'll have to import collections).

Comment: Hi JoeL, I hear what you're saying, which is why the "if a._lineItems != []:" is in there - it's not working properly anyway, but in this example, I shouldn't have reached that base case yet anyway. I'm trying to iterate a list, which I proved was a list by printing it out right before trying to iterate. That's where I'm stuck (unless I'm still misunderstanding?)

Comment: "if a._lineItems != []" means "if a.lineItems is not the empty list", not "if it is not a list".