# List of objects is not iterable & call variable being in other function

Tags: python, oop

I have seen this post but still can not figure out my problem.
[Python iteration of list of objects "not iterable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521739/python-iteration-of-list-of-objects-not-iterable)
My question also has a second part which is: 
**How can I use variable which was created in one function in other.** 
I will start with it. Answers that I googled or fined in SO:

***1 variant - globals***

```
def func1():
    global value2,value1
    value1 = 1
    value2 = 2
def func2():
    global value2,value1
    do smth with value1 
    do smth with value2

func1()
func2()
```

But this is bad idea, due to some reason. I do not get still too much, like I am using same namespaces, and limit variants of naming variables. And some unpredictable behavior is much easier to get..(that is what I understood)

***2 variant -functions are objects, and everything in Python is an object!***

```
def func1():
    func1.value1 = 1
    func1.value2 = 2
def func2():
    do smth with func1.value1
    do smth with func1.value2

func1()
func2()
```

This is a better idea?

***3 variant - use return***

I know that everybody says : try to make your function to return some value which you will use further. But! I have a function draw() which is rerunning 60 times per second, that is why writing like this is a mess:

```
def draw():
    variable = some_function()
```

My function will be starting 60times per second, where I need just 1 time till specific trigger/button is pressed.

**Finally my main question**
Here is my code:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        ...
    def draw(self, canvas, pos):
        ...
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand_list = []
    def draw(self, canvas, pos):
        ...
    deff add_card(self)

def deal():
    test_hand = Deck() # from the Deck we fulfill cards to player and computer hands
    test_hand.shuffle()
    deal.player_hand, computer_hand = Hand(), Hand()

def draw(canvas):
    i = 0
    for card in deal.player_hand:
        deal.player_hand.draw(canvas, [300, 300])
```

And finnaly I get.

> TypeError: 'Hand' object is not iterable

Somewhere type of self.hand_list changed from list to a non list. Or a problem is somewhere deeper. Because when I look at what interpreter is printing - he is printing 2 Cards of some suit and rank as 1 object. I do not know where to start from. 
I would be really helpful for advices.

> I have got Learning Python by Mark Lutz, maybe there are some topics 
>   should look deeper at?

Thanks everybody!

> Here is the link to my code. You can run it from there.
>   http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user35_zXdT3D8RpqJXoVb.py

Comment: Could you please provide a working code sample that we can run and see the error generated for ourselves?

Comment: "Somewhere type of self.hand_list changed from list to a non list." Not according to your error, which says `TypeError: 'Hand' object is not iterable`. According to that, you're not iterating over `self.hand_list` -- you're iterating over `self` (or trying to).

Comment: Thank you, Two-Bit Alchemist.I have added full code of my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the `draw` method:

```
for card in deal.player_hand:
    ...
```

You're iterating over `player_hand`, which is an object of the Hand class, and not the cards within that hand. You probably want to do `for card in deal.player_hand.hand_list`.

Comment: Could you be pleased to answer to the first question?

Comment: Not really, because I don't understand it at all. Why are you calling the function 60 times a second, and why does that mean you can't call the other function?

Comment: I am trying to make kind of 'Lite' Blackjack, hence it needs graphical interface. I am using simplegui module one of which ideas is: app draw itself every 1/60 of a second.

Comment: But why would that call a new hand every 60 seconds? You just need to call the function when the button is pressed, surely.

Comment: I need to have from 4 to 5 cards on the board(depending on the game status). Drawing every card on the board is done by calling draw function.Draw function is the function that is called 60times per sec. If I will pass card as an output of my_hand_function, my_hand_function will be called 60 times per sec. and hence there will be always new cards. Am I clear? Or you telling me that the way I do is not so good?